# Disable button using GetElementsByClassName in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

[I expect such a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNdQO.png)
I use a primeNG component FileUpload. I have tree buttons: choose, upload and cancel. And I want to try disable buttons like "Upload" and "Cancel" after uploaded files throught using class name. But it's not work.

```
<p-fileUpload 
  customUpload="true" 
  multiple="multiple"
  (uploadHandler)="onUpload($event)"
  (click)="disableButton()">
</p-fileUpload>

import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent {
pBtn: any = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-state-disabled") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLInputElement>;

disableButton(){
this.pBtn[0].disabled = true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The disabled button is an attribute not a style.

You could do something similar to below and bind the disabled attribute to some boolean you can alter whilst uploading files. Angular provides databinding like this so you don't have to directly modify the dom from your typescript file.

`<button [disabled]="disabled"></button>`

```
disable() {
    this.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely how to disable buttons. Avoid directly manipulating the DOM wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

[As PrimeNG dosumentation says:](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)

> - showUploadButton - Defines the visibility of upload button for Client-side FileUpload.
> - showCancelButton - Defines the visibility of cancel button for Client-side FileUpload.

You can hide your buttons or just upload button through properties `showUploadButton` or `showButtons`. It depends what you need:

```
    <p-fileUpload 
      #myfileUpload          
      [disabled]="isDisabled"
      [showUploadButton]="isShowUploadButton"
      [showCancelButton]="isSshowCancelButton"
      customUpload="true" 
      multiple="multiple"
      (uploadHandler)="onUpload($event)"
      (click)="disableButton()">
    </p-fileUpload>
```

TypeScript:

```
isShowUploadButton = true;
isSshowCancelButton = true;
isDisabled = false;


disableButton(){        
    this.isDisabled = true;
    this.isShowUploadButton = false;
    this.isSshowCancelButton = false;
}
```

Comment: Directly modifying the DOM like this should only really be edge case. Binding to the buttons' `disabled` attribute is more usual.

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara there are no such properties like `disableUploadButton` or `disableCancelButton` in API of fileUpload control. All available properties are here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara  However, if you write styles, then user will have a chance to click your buttons. However, it is not desired.

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara by applying styles you just modifies user interface. However, user will be available to execute your buttons `disableUploadButton ` and `disableCancelButton`.